# Why is VirusTotal returning this error?

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to use VirusTotal's public API to scan files. This is my code:

```
$post_url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan';    

$filemime = exec("file -b --mime-type '$file_to_scan'");

$post = array('apikey' => $virustotal_api_key, 'file' => '@' . realpath($file_to_scan) . ';type=' . $filemime . ';filename=' . $name);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Expect:'));
$api_reply = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$api_reply_array = json_decode($api_reply, true);
```

Whenever I run this code, I get the following error:

```
[response_code] => 0
[verbose_msg] => Invalid submission format, the uploaded file must travel as a multipart MIME message, please review the documentation
```

I've spent multiple hours trying to figure this out, but it just won't work. Can anyone point me in the right directions?

This is the `print_r` of `$post` in the above code:

```
[apikey] => xxx
[file] => @/absolute/path/to/file.exe;type=application/octet-stream;filename=file.exe
```

Thanks!

Comment: Comment this line: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);` then try it again.

Comment: Doesn't fix it. I already tried adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));`, still didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, after assistance from VirusTotal themselves (kudos, Karl). The problem was how PHP 5.6 changed cURL. If you are on PHP 5.6, you need to add:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);`

Comment: FYI: This is no longer supported in PHP 7. You'll need to use the CURLFile construct: http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php

Comment: That did the trick for me, too – thanks and +1. Unfortunately, with PHP 7 this throws a warning: `curl_setopt(): Disabling safe uploads is no longer supported`. Though the PHP docu doesn't (yet) mention it, this seems to be deprecated now (as redburn already pointed out), so the solution no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

The line to fix is

```
$post = array('apikey' => $virustotal_api_key, 'file' => '@' . realpath($file_to_scan) . ';type=' . $filemime . ';filename=' . $name);
```

This must be changed to:

```
$cfile = new CURLFile(realpath($file_to_scan),$filemime,$name);
$post = array('apikey' => $virustotal_api_key, 'file' => $cfile);
```

Then it also works with PHP 7 :)

Comment: PS: Be welcome to use my [virustotal](https://github.com/IzzySoft/virustotal) class :)